# How to get Index of an Item in ICollection<T>

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, collections, indexer

I have this list of cars

```
ICollection<Cars> Cars
```

and I also have a single car object, which I know is in the ICollection how do I get the index/position of the car in the list? I need to add it to a list of strings

This is what I have so far:

```
var index = cars.Where(b=> b.Id == car.id).Single().iWantTheIndex
stringList.Add(index)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: LINQ does not have a `FindIndex()` method.

Comment: `var index = cars.Select((b, i) => new { car = b, index = i }).Single(b => b.car.Id == car.id).index;`

Comment: Does `ICollection<T>` even have indexes?  How do you get an element *from* `Cars` based on its index?

Comment: @David No, `ICollection`'s don't necessarily have indexes.

Comment: @BlakeThingstad: Clever, though that's adding an artificial index based on whatever the current state of `cars` is.  The system provides no guarantee that the same "index" would match the same object in any future operation.  One could, on the very next line of code, attempt to fetch the same object from `cars` based on that index (likely using `.Skip()` and `.First()` or something of that nature) and get a completely different object.

Comment: @David would it work if the collection was initialized as a collection that does index its objects (such as List)? The OP would still want to seriously consider changing their code structure, but just wondering.

Comment: @BlakeThingstad: Directing to Servy's answer below, yes.  If the OP wants to use an ordered collection, `ICollection<T>` is the wrong type to use.  The OP is looking for `IList<T>`.

Comment: @BlakeThingstad If you're going to require the implementing type to be an ordered collection that requires all items to have a meaninful index, then *actually require that* by using an interface whose contract requires those things (`IList<T>`) rather than one that doesn't (`ICollection<T>`).  It's a very bad idea to use an interface whose contract doesn't actually specify all of the things you need, and to just hope that anyone using that code knows that they're actually supposed to provide specific types of implementations.

Comment: An Index is usually a number, so what exactly do you mean by adding it to a list of strings?

Comment: I get it I get it now.... my question was slightly floored from the start.... a Icollection is not a list

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want to use an indexed collection then you should use `IList<T>`, not `ICollection<T>`.  An `ICollection<T>` is something that you can enumerate, add and remove items for, and get the count of, that's all.  An `IList<T>` is a collection in which the items are in a specified order, and can be accessed based on their position in the list.

Because an `ICollection<T>` doesn't necessarily represent an ordered collection, you cannot get a meaningful "index" of an item.  Items don't necessarily *have* a position.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the index of the *current* iteration:

```
var index = cars.Select((c, i) => new{ Index = i, Car = c })
                .Where(item => item.Car.Id == car.id)
                .Single()
                .Index;

stringList.Add(index);
```

Please note that the *next* iteration may have a different order (depending on the actual implementation of your `ICollection<>`) and may result in a completely different index, so be careful what you use this index for.

Comment: This index doesn't provide anything of value though. The collection isn't ordered. It could have an entirely different index the next time you enumerate it.

Comment: @Servy You are right, next time you call this, depending on the actual implementation behind the interface, you may just get a different index. However, it's not up to me to say whether the *current* index of that car is of any value. I can only say this is a way to get it.

Comment: But you don't *have* the current index of the value.  You have the value of what the index used to be in a sequence that can never be accessed again.  You don't actually have the index of the item in the collection.

Comment: @Servy You are right, *current* was the wrong choice of words. *Last* would be a better description.

Comment: @nvoigt Can you add some commentary onto the answer so that it can be of more value to others in the future?

Comment: @DrRobLang Done :)